# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate after adding certificate file xxx.pem path in php.ini file

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, curl, yoast

In wordpress admin panel yoast premimum plugin is not validating due to the CURL 60 error. Yoast trying to verify the yoast activation but curl 60 error blocking to access that external url from server.

Also we have added curl.cainfo ="xxxxx.pem"; in php.ini but same issue happening.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsyg0.png)

Comment: It is better to provide logs as text rather than in an image. Also you could try out the editing and formatting options on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code in your curl request to Ignore verification of SSL certificate.

```
curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Here $ch is the Object of curl_init(); function.